# Return the id after insert or select

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, insert, plpgsql, concurrency

I want to build a function which will insert an email if the email value doesn't exist in the table and return the `email_id` of the row. How can I do this?
Also how can I return the id if the email was not inserted and it already exist in the DB? Do I need to perform another `SELECT`?

```
BEGIN;
  LOCK TABLE mailing_list IN SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE MODE;
  INSERT INTO mailing_list (email)
  SELECT 'email'
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (
     SELECT * FROM mailing_list WHERE email='email'
   );
COMMIT;
```

I have tried adding the `returning id` but it doesn't work. I got:

> query has no destination for result data

[Sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e5048/1)

Comment: Please show us the complete function

Comment: @alex: That would be a case of "INSERT or SELECT". And it's typically cheaper to handle possible race conditions than to lock the whole table. Details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15939902/is-select-or-insert-in-a-function-prone-to-race-conditions/15950324#15950324

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter thanks, I found your post a bit later after I've posted this, just a quick question, do I need the loop, or whats the loop for? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[@a_horse already explained](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/89646/3684) how to avoid the error message you saw.

Here is a simple variant of the related version we have been referring to:

- [Is SELECT or INSERT in a function prone to race conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15950324/939860)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_email_insel(_email text, OUT email_id int) AS
$func$
BEGIN

LOOP
   BEGIN  -- start inner block inside loop to handle possible exception

   SELECT INTO email_id  m.email_id FROM mailing_list m WHERE m.email = _email;

   IF NOT FOUND THEN
      INSERT INTO mailing_list (email) VALUES (_email)
      RETURNING mailing_list.email_id INTO email_id;
   END IF;

   EXCEPTION WHEN UNIQUE_VIOLATION THEN     -- inserted in concurrent session.
      RAISE NOTICE 'It actually happened!'; -- hardly ever happens
   END;

   EXIT WHEN email_id IS NOT NULL;          -- else keep looping
END LOOP;

END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/fc6f34/3)

You only need the loop to deal with a possible race condition: If a concurrent transaction writes the same `email` value in between `SELECT` and `INSERT`, you would get a unique violation - which is handled properly here. This is assuming a `UNIQUE` constraint (or a `UNIQUE` index) on `email`, obviously.

The [alternative with CTEs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15950324/939860) runs as *one* SQL statement. So here the overhead is slightly smaller (simpler queries), but the time frame for a race condition is slightly bigger. Especially if the row frequently already exists, this is a bit faster.
Read the detailed explanation over there and pick the approach that best fits your use case.

Answer (score 7):

You need to store the value that you want to return somewhere:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_get(ikey text)
  returns integer
  AS
$func$
DECLARE 
  l_id integer;
BEGIN
  LOCK TABLE foo IN SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE MODE;
  INSERT INTO foo (type)
  SELECT ikey
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (
     SELECT * FROM foo WHERE type=ikey
   )
   returning id into l_id; --< store the returned ID in local variable
   return l_id; --< return this variable
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

You could have done that with the original function and an `OUT` parameter as well. In that case you just need to use `returning id into out_key;`

Comment: Thank you for the help, can I use this now and in case that the data EXISTS in the table return the id of the row?

Comment: @alex: see here for a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15939902/330315